# Reference ViewChild content Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I create a directive in **Angular 2** and in this directive I have to access `Component`. For that I used the `ViewChild` (this approach worked in normal component, but it is not working in the directive context.

That is my directive:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, NavParams} from "ionic-angular";
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from "ionic-angular";
import {ComponentBase} from "../../component.base";

@Component({
    selector: "header-content",
    directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "build/pages/components/header-content/header.content.html"
})
export class HeaderContentComponent {
    @ViewChild(Component) protected component;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.component.type);
    }
}
```

In the `console.log` I get the following exception:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

How can I access `Component` from my directive?

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately I've pasted the wrong code in here, but still the same problem.

I need to get `Content` and not `Component` as mentioned.

So here is the code. `Content` is still undefined:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, NavParams, Content} from "ionic-angular";
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from "ionic-angular";
import {ComponentBase} from "../../component.base";

@Component({
    selector: "header-content",
    directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "build/pages/components/header-content/header.content.html"
})
export class HeaderContentComponent {
    @ViewChild(Content) protected content: Content;

    public toolbarActive: boolean = false;

    public toggleToolbar() {
        this.toolbarActive = !this.toolbarActive;

        if (this.toolbarActive) {
            // this.content.removeCssClass("no-scroll");
            // this.content.addCssClass("scroll");
        } else {
            // this.content.removeCssClass("scroll");
            // this.content.addCssClass("no-scroll");
        }

        // this.content.resize();
    }

    protected ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.content);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I created a Plunker with the code, check the console and you will see **undefined**

https://plnkr.co/edit/ayFskPyDRlpYDkMEapDL?p=preview

**EDIT:**

After accepting the answer below (it works on Plunker), but it's not working in my Visual Studio. I get the following error:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

[image]

New Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ayFskPyDRlpYDkMEapDL?p=preview

Comment: Hi did you ever get to the bottom of this? I want to be able to access Content from within a custom component. I have the same typescript error if I try to use `@Host(Content) private content: Content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it within `ngAfterViewInit` hook

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.component.type);
}
```

**Update:**

You can use `Host` decorator to do that:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Host} from "@angular/core";
import {Content, IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
    selector: "hello-world",
    directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: 'src/hello-world.html'
})
export class HelloWorld {
  constructor(@Host(Content) private content: Content) {
    console.log(this.content);
  }
}
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oAelma66CYSd1Litc5aq?p=preview)**

Comment: Wow! I've committed a big mistake. It's not `Component`what I'm trying to get, it's `Content`. I'll update my post.

Comment: Please check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/JTL0aMcnh748parhbbfj?p=preview What's wrong here?

Comment: this plunker is about a component. I'm using a directive. I can access `Content` from a component, but not from a directive.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on the plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ayFskPyDRlpYDkMEapDL?p=preview 

but I'm still working on it, but you can already see the code and what I expect

Comment: Use `Host` decorator to do that https://plnkr.co/edit/oAelma66CYSd1Litc5aq?p=preview

Comment: See my update, the `Host` receives no parameters. I had to inject Content as a provider: See the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ayFskPyDRlpYDkMEapDL?p=preview

Comment: Try use it `constructor(private content: Content) {`

Comment: That is what I did, check my plunker. But I get a different behavior I was expecting. The original code is too big to publish on Plunker, but at the end what I need to do is to resize the content with `this.content.resize()` - The problem is now it's not resizing. It resizes only if I use `@ViewChild`direct in the component. Check this issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/1fe1c1e291b8633dbaf34f4409b5b22bde19b109#commitcomment-18566815

Comment: That is what I did. Unfortunatelly ionic is not resizing the content. I opened a bug there: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7645

Comment: In your plunker you use `ViewChild` but i use constructor parameter

Comment: Remove `providers: [Content]` from component metadata. You create new instance of `Content`

Comment: Ok. Then I get this.

**ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Content!**

Losing hopes!

Comment: Where is this error https://plnkr.co/edit/kjwIwpLhJBnH1uAa84wh?p=preview

Comment: Sure Plunker is resolving it, for sure. I use Visual Studio and here I'm getting this error. :( I also don't see how can we inject `Content` without registering it, right? This is plunker resolving things.

Comment: Try local on your machine

Comment: Hm.. Try this option `constructor(@Inject(Content) private content: Content){}`

Comment: The same error:

EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/subjects/subjects.html:1:4
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Content!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor]

Comment: based on what ionic people said me once, content is not a service and should not be injected. It should be acessed via `@ViewChild`...then we come to the original error, `@ViewChild(Content)` does not work from the directive

Comment: It works for me on local machine. I use visual studio code. `ViewChild` gets reference only from component template

Comment: Weird. OK...I'll keep on trying and update you once I find a solution. Maybe Ionic team gets back to me.

Comment: This is just the Plunker right? This might work, but the resize method is not going to work. I found a solution and I'll update the Plunker with it, stay tuned :D

Comment: Ok. I found a solution - In our base component class, I added a `@ViewChild(Content) protected content: Content` then I'm passing this to my directive. My directive gets this and use then the **resize** method. It looks good, but for me - gut feeling - this is still an ionic issue. I'm going to update the Plunker.

Comment: As promised I updated the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ayFskPyDRlpYDkMEapDL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in @ViewChild(Content) from your page into ion-header as a directive input.

So in your page, you have:

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
```

Your header looks something like:

```
<ion-header [yourDirective]="content">
```

And then in your directive class:

```
@Input('yourDirective') content: Content;
```